# Unable to increase size(height, width) of react-phone-input-2

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to use `react-phone-input-2` in my form as it is providing many features like flag and formatting number etc..

But I am not able to customise the input using my own css. eg: height, width

Also I have imported the material css given by the same package as I have all other components using material ui.

```
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/material.css';
```

```
<div>
<PhoneInput 
   country={'us'}
   value={this.props.receiverPhone}
   className={classes.phoneNumber}
   fullWidth="true"
   onChange={(phone) => this.props.changePhoneNumber(phone)}
/>
</div>
```

my styles

```
    phoneNumber: {
      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        width: '95%',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        width: '93%',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        width: '82%',
      },
      padding: '5px',
      height: '40px',
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    },
```

I have also tried giving `style={{width:100, height:40}}` and `InputProps{{className:classes.phoneNumber}}`as props to `<PhoneInput>` but looks like even this is also not working.
Is there any other way to fix this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could be helpful

```
 <PhoneInput
      inputStyle={{color:'green'}}
      containerStyle={{margin:'20px'}}
      buttonStyle={{}}
      dropdownStyle={{height:'50px'}}
      country={"us"}
      value="1425652"
      onChange={phone => console.log({ phone })}
      />
```

Or

```
  <PhoneInput
  containerClass='.....' //css class name
  inputClass='.....'
  buttonClass='.....'
  dropdownClass='.....'
  searchClass='.....'
  country={"us"}
  value="1425652"
  onChange={phone => console.log({ phone })}
  />
```

Or

```
.form-control {
  background-color: rgb(253, 214, 214) !important;
  color: rgb(104, 7, 60);
  height: 55px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
}
.react-tel-input {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}

.flag-dropdown {
  background-color: rgb(240, 205, 159) !important;
}
```

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-phone-input-2-m1058)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I achieve it:

```js
.react-tel-input {
 font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}

.react-tel-input .form-control {
 margin-top: 0 !important;
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 height: 3.5rem !important;
 position: relative;
 letter-spacing: .01rem;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 margin-top: 0 !important;
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was customizing the containerClass="w-100" but not the inputClass="w-100"

When I only do the container class the phone input only shows about 70% width. So make sure you customize the inputClass property of the PhoneInput hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the best way to aplay your style in React JS is by using styled-compoment

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css";
```

you can use it like this :

```
const PhoneStyled = styled(PhoneInput)`
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999 !important;
`;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34795966)